# Enterprise Wireless Distribution doesn't work iOS 5.1.1

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ios5, enterprise-distribution

I've been searching all over and cannot seem to find an answer to this.  I'm hoping someone here can help.  I'm somewhat new to iOS app development so please bear with me if my terminology is off.

I'm working on an in-house Enterprise iPad app for the company I work for.  We have an Enterprise Developer account and we've created all the necessary Certificates and Provisioning Profiles for Distribution (Distribution Certificate, Distribution Provisioning Profile). We are aiming to use the Wireless Distribution Method on one of our websites.  I've created the necessary files (.ipa & manifest .plist) and uploaded and linked to the manifest file according to Apple's instructions.

When I test the wireless distribution method using iPads running iOS 6 it works flawlessly.  When I try testing on an iPad running iOS 5.1.1 I get "Unable to Download Application" with options "Done" or "Retry".  Clicking "Retry" doesn't seem to help.

The app's build settings in xCode are set to

**Base SDK: Latest iOS (iOS 6.0)**

**iOS Deployment Target: 4.3**

I've tried Apple's troubleshooting suggestions for Wireless Distribution.  I am able to successfully install the app on the 5.1.1 device using Apple Configurator so I know the app actually works on the device.

From what I've seen, many other people have had issues with iOS 5.1.1 but I couldn't locate a clear answer on how to fix this wireless distribution issue.  We still have some of the original iPads being used in our company that are unable to upgrade to 6.0 and we want to be able to support them if possible.

Is this just an issue with iOS 5.1.1 that was never resolved?

Is there another setting in xCode that I might be missing?

Do I need to change something else on our server (we've already added the appropriate MIME types as per Apple instructions)?

Any help/suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had a rather obvious issue - I had named my icon file Icon.png but had listed it in the manifest as icon.png.  This worked fine in iOS 6, but not in 5.1.1.  Sometimes it's the easiest solutions.
The documentation requests an icon that is 57x57, but I upped it to 72x72, since it is an iPad only app.  That may help as well.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same problem for distribute InHouse app to iPhone iOS 5.1.
It is solved after adding Large Image Url to the .plist.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well. If you shut down the iOS device and restart it, the app will be there ... just a workaround that helped us here. But I´ll try to fix it withe the icon issues in the other posts